# Two men on a road

Tags: situation

Two men are on the side of a long, straight road that runs east to west, waiting for a tow truck. They stand facing opposite directions, one east, one west, in order to scan the road.

"Stop making faces at me," one says to the other.

"Only if you stop sticking your tongue out at me," the first replies.

The two men are looking straight ahead and not using any mirrors or reflections - how can they see one another?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably:

> The man facing east is standing further west than the one facing west; the question never states they are standing back-to-back.

Comment: Reminds me of rot13(Bar svar qnl va gur zvqqyr bs gur avtug, gjb qrnq zra tbg hc gb n svtug, onpx gb onpx gurl snprq rnpu bgure, qerj gurve fjbeqf naq fubg rnpu bgure.)

Comment: Reminds me of rot13(Gjb zra ner snpvat rnfg naq jrfg erfcrpgviryl. Bar bs gur gjb zra vf abg snpvat rnfg. [Ubj vf guvf cbffvoyr?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148868/but-one-of-them-is-not-a-nickel-why-is-that-a-riddle))

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps few more tags, such as

> riddle, word play are apt for this puzzle and

based on these, it can be stated that

> both men are standing in *those directions, which are opposite - as East is opposite to West or vice-versa* - which translates to - they are facing each other, literally.

Comment: I dunno about [tag:riddle]

Comment: @Brandon_J this is actually a riddle.

Comment: @Quark-epoch No it's not (not by the Puzzling SE definition of [tag:riddle]).

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be that they might be

> calling on Skype or another video calling app.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for editing but how do you add this spoiler.Will you please specify a bit?

Comment: You can [edit] the answer to view its new 'source code'; the secret is the `>!`. See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers